# What is so special about += operator?

Tags: python, parsing, variable-assignment

I wrote a code similar to the following and it gives me the `local variable 'a' referenced before assignment` error. When I changed that `a += [2]` into `a.append(2)`, it worked.

```py
def f():
   a = [1]
   def f1():
      a += [2] # => no error with a.append(2)
   f1()
   print(a)
```

Why? Why the parser can't recognize the outside `a` with `+=`?

Comment: Because it is an *assignment*, and *all assignments to a variable mark that variable as local by the compiler*

Comment: @Matthias no, `+=` modifies the object in-place, `a = a + [2]` does not.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I stand corrected.

Comment: I think Matthias is correct. Do you have evidence for your claim juanpa?

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense, didn't know that, I tried `global a`, also didn't work, I guess that location isn't a real global. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make it work if I want to keep the assignment and the a in the outside function?

Comment: @MikeClark just try it out for yourself... it is also basic Python knowledge. Note, `a += b` strictly speaking is up to the type to define the behavior, because it is essentially a call to `a.__iadd__(b)`, but the *whole point* of these operators was to provided *in-place* operations, see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/ and the built-in types respect this convention

Comment: @moon yes, it is definetly not `global`, use `nonlocal`, but really, `.append` makes the most sense here

Comment: @MikeClark Check the `id` of `a` after `a = a + [2]` and `a += [1]`.

Comment: Of course, if a type is immutable, e.g. `int`, then `a += b` will work equivalently to `a = a + b`

Comment: @Matthias `+=` for lists is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Comment: I couldn't think of how to tell whether it was inplace or a copy. Checking the `id` seems to be the way to do that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MikeClark alternatively, `x = []; y = x; x += [a]; print(x, y)`

Comment: It seems `a += b` when `b` is not iterable is equivalent to `a += [b]`. This I didn't know. I wonder if the first form is slightly faster due to no temporary 1-element array? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @MikeClark mmm no, if `a` is a `list` and `b` is not iterable, that would throw a `TypeError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `a = ['a']; a += 'b'; print(a)` try it!

Comment: @MikeClark `"b"` is iterable. Try that with `"abc"` to see what's going on, it is equivalent only in the case of length-1 strings. Now try it with something that is actually not itereable, e.g. a `float`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I'm dumb. I forgot that strings are iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an assignment to `a`. It's basically syntactic sugar for

```
a = a.__iadd__([2])
```

The assignment makes `a` a local variable when the code is generated, but then the RHS of the assignment tries to access that variable before at runtime it is defined.

`a.append(2)`, on the other hand, is *not* an assignment. `a` is a free variable whose value is taken from the closest enclosing scope.

If you want to assign to a non-local variable, you need to declare the name as non-local first.

```
def f():
   a = [1]
   def f1():
      nonlocal a
      a += [2]
   f1()
   print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner! by "enclosing scope", does it just refer to a function/class/global? is there some special meaning about "enclosing"?

Comment: Nothing really special. `f1` is defined in the body of `f`, so we say that `f`'s scope encloses `f1`'s. `f` is defined in the global scope, so we say that the global scope encloses `f`'s. (We could stretch and say that the global scope encloses `f1`'s scope, too, but `f`'s is the *closest* enclosing scope to `f1`'s.) The built-in scope encloses all global scopes (which are only global to its module, not the entire process.)